# Access sprite node by its name

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am currently building an iOS game using Objective-C in SpriteKit.

Each asteroid gets an identifier when they are spawned, using this code:

```
[self.asteroid setName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid-%i", self.asteroidCounter]];
```

Now, I want to be able to remove specific asteroids from the parent based on their integer name. I tried this code, but it was seen as an error:

```
[self.asteroid withName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid-%i", self.asteroidCounter] removeFromParent];
```

Is there a proper way to achieve this effect?

Thanks in advance!

PS: [here is an image of the faulty code in Xcode, if it helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UqUq.png)

Comment: Read the error. Fix the error. And, if still having a question, *include* the error. To the 'question': Yes, there is a way to "do this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are accessing through properties:

```
[[self.asteroid withName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid-%i", self.asteroidCounter]] removeFromParent];
```

If asteroid is a child of self, you could also say (this would be the sprite-kit way to do it):

```
[[self childNodeWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid-%i", self.asteroidCounter]] removeFromParent];
```

This is assuming that your property asteroidCounter returns the right value.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some brackets:

`[[self.asteroid withName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"asteroid-%i", self.asteroidCounter]] removeFromParent];`